# determine custom templates in custom module hook_preprocess_page function

Tags: theming

I'd like to create a module that use a set of custom templates depending on http status code

Very well inspired by 
[Custom template for 404 error pages](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34277/custom-template-for-404-error-pages)

Here is where i am so far

```
function my_module_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $header = drupal_get_http_header('status');
    if ($header == '404 Not Found') {
      //this
      $vars['template_files'][] = 'page__404';
      //or that 
      $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__404';
    }
}
```

in my module templates folder , i have created a

```
page--404.tpl.php
```

this template is not overtaken !?

EDIT : 
i have also tried what's in [there](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53680/override-field-template-with-custom-module)

```
function my_module_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
$header = drupal_get_http_header('status');
if ($header == '404 Not Found') {
  $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__404';
}
}


function my_module_theme() {
  return array(
    'page__404' => array(
      'template' => 'page__404',
      'variables' => array('xxx' => null), 
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module')
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override field template with custom module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53680/override-field-template-with-custom-module)

Comment: Okay, in that case let's do some debugging. If you don't have Drush, get it :p. `drush vset theme_debug 1` will add markup to the HTML so you can view tpl suggestions from your browser inspector. Make sure the ones you added are there. Also, make sure you don't have any dblog errors about your tpl not being found.

Comment: fantastic , page--404.tpl.php was suggested but the one taken in account was page__404

Comment: To fix that and stay with standards, you can change `'template' => 'page__404'` to `'template' => 'page--404'`. The suggestions use underscore, but the tpl uses dashes.

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_module_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
$header = drupal_get_http_header('status');
if ($header == '404 Not Found') {
  $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__404';
}
}


function my_module_theme() {
  return array(
    'page__404' => array(
      'template' => 'page__404',
      'variables' => array('xxx' => null), 
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module')
    ),
  );
}
```

thanks to sareed, drush vset theme_debug 1 allowed me to see :

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- CALL: theme('page') -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * page--404.tpl.php
   * page--psnmssss.tpl.php
   * page.tpl.php
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'my_module/page__404.tpl.php' -->

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'my_module/page__404.tpl.php' -->
```

so i changed page--404 to page__404 and it worked

how could i restrict the template suggestion only for the content region of the page ?

Comment: Instead of replacing a page tpl, replace the region tpl. Use the same method, but different preprocess `theme_preprocess_region` instead of page.