# How to set a theme for a 403 access denied?

Tags: redirection

When a user clicks a link to a Drupal site and are denied access because they need to login, they get a 403 access denied screen inviting them to login. I want to set a responsive theme because some users will be using phones.  I've tried to use the Themekey module to set something other than the admin theme (which is Seven) setting path:node_alias to the redirection which is user/login?destination=whatever  However this doesn't work. Any ideas please?  I'd much prefer a non coding solution, if possible!  Thanks - using Drupal 7.

Comment: Have you seen this post, https://www.powercms.in/blog/drupal-7-theming-403-and-404-error-pages-drupal-7?

Comment: Thanks, looks useful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom template for 404 error pages](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34277/custom-template-for-404-error-pages)